# Why use joint_state_publisher?

Tags: ros, joint-state-publisher, jointstate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I was looking through the documentation for the [joint_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher) package. I can see the use case for wanting so publish and set joint states via the GUI, but what is the purpose of having the node subscribe to incoming `sensor_msgs/JointState` messages?

It seems to me that if you are working in hardware, there is no reason to do that. The node will just subscribe via:

```
source_list (list of strings, default: [])
A list of topics to listen on for sensor_msgs/JointState messages.
```

and spit them back out again.

Does anybody have any insights on this? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207728/why-use-joint_state_publisher?/) by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) on ROS Answers with karma: 593 on 2015-04-23

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

joint_state_publisher acts as an aggregate. The [robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) node takes a single message with the state of all joints in your robot. So if you have, for example, multiple nodes each publishing a single joint state, the joint_state_publisher subscribes to all the individual topics and combines them.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2015-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) on 2015-04-23**:
Great, thanks for the answer! That makes sense. Can I then assume it will aggregate all the JointState messages within it's output publish rate? So if I set it to 10Hz it will aggregate all the JointState messages in that 1/10th of a second before it publishes next?